# Updating list of dictionaries in python using map

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a list that looks like this:

```
users = [{'id': 11, 'name': 'First'}, {'id': 22, 'name': 'Second'}, {'id':33, 'name': 'Third'}]
```

What I want to do is to update a users name by passing id, creating new user, and replacing old one with new user.
I want to get list of updated users, like this:

```
updated_users = list(map(update, users))
```

If I could send id to update func as argument, what I want to do, would look something like this:

```
def update(id):
    if user['id'] == id:
        new_user = some_fun()
        user = new_user
        return user
```

How should my update function look like?

Comment: How would you know the 'updated' ones ?

Comment: Yes, I know that map sends a user by argument to update(), but how do I chose wich user I want to edit?

Comment: why use map? why cant the update function just take an ID and a list of users and enumerate over the user list and update the matching user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to use map and I think it's a wrong approach because map isn't for this kind of things (you could make it work for sure but it wouldn't be the way to go)

You can do something like that:

```
users = [{'id': 11, 'name': 'First'}, {'id': 22, 'name': 'Second'}, {'id':33, 'name': 'Third'}]

def update(id, new_name):
    for user in users:
        if user["id"] == id:
            user["name"] = new_name
            return
    users.append({'id':id,'name':new_name}) # if not exist add user

print(users)
update(11,"Last")
update(1, "New_First")
print(users)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 11, 'name': 'First'}, {'id': 22, 'name': 'Second'}, {'id': 33, 'name': 'Third'}]
[{'id': 11, 'name': 'Last'}, {'id': 22, 'name': 'Second'}, {'id': 33, 'name': 'Third'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'New_First'}]
```